# Create Socket Errors on Purpose / Python Script

Tags: python, sockets, connection

I want to create socket errors (By doing things, obviously) but I've no idea how I should test if my script handles errors properly (If it dectes them.)

Currently, my code is this:

```
except socket.error as err:
    print "Connection lost, waiting..."
    time.sleep(5)
```

In theory, it should handle all the socket errors, print and then sleep (It's a part of a while loop.).

Any idea of how can I test it to see how it handles errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `raise` statement:

```
try:
    raise socket.error
except socket.error as err:
    print "Connection lost, waiting..."
    time.sleep(5)
```

Yet another example:

```
try:
    raise AttributeError
except AttributeError:
    print 'Sorry'
#Sorry
```

Also take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957829/how-to-use-raise-keyword-in-python) and [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions)

Comment: Sorry for being late! I forgot to reply here. yes, DawG - I wasn't aware of this and it worked. It indeed returned what I wanted it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hah - Sorry. didn't mean to, I'd give 5000 points to everyone. I just plainly forget. Not that "I get the question" and I run, just forgot. Sorry.