# Why is the error handling not working for None input?

Tags: python

```
def copy_list(t):
try:
    if type(t) is list:
        t_copy=[]
        n=len(t)
        i=0
        while i<n:
            t_copy.append(t[i])
            i+=1
        return t_copy
except TypeError:
        return "Not a list"
```

The problem says that I should write a function which takes a list of integers as an input and returns a copy of it. It should raise an exception if the input is not a list.
I am unable to understand that why my code is unable to raise an exception if the value is not of the list type or when the input is None?

Comment: Because your `if` statement will only trigger on `t` being a list, none of the other statements will try to run on non lists, so you never hit any code that will raise an exemption.

Comment: So how can I modify my code in order to reach the except statement?

Comment: You're catching `TypeError`; which line in the `try` block do you expect to throw that exception? (Furthermore, since you're *catching* the exception, you're violating the stipulation that your function should *throw* an exception. Since the function is supposed to throw, you shouldn't catch errors there.)

Comment: This is not a good use of `try..except` . Just `if..else` should be sufficient.

Comment: @karthikr      I used a if-else also but it is not able to check for None input

Comment: Perhaps they want you to use `assert type(t) is list`.

Comment: [How to clone or copy a list in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/33732)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The try/except block is used for gracefully handling exceptions that are thrown by the interpreter when an unexpected or illegal value is encountered, not for raising exceptions intentionally. For that you want the `raise` keyword. See this question: [How to use "raise" keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957829/how-to-use-raise-keyword-in-python)

As a suggestion, your code could look something like this:

```
def copy_list(t):
    if isinstance(t, list):
        t_copy=[]
        n=len(t)
        i=0
        while i<n:
            t_copy.append(t[i])
            i+=1
        return t_copy
    else:
        raise Exception('Not a list')
```

Edit: I think you're also going to want the `isinstance` function, and I have edited the code accordingly. Info on that can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance).

Comment: You're welcome! Consider accepting answers when they work for you, and welcome to the site! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: In the interests of fairness, having commented on the other answers, this answer passes the tests with flying colours.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't raise an exception because you check whether the type of `t` is a list using `if type(t) is list`. When you provide `None` as an input, it doesn't pass the `if` statement and falls through so nothing is returned and no exception is raised.

You can remove the `if` statement to raise your exception. `n=len(t)` will trigger the exception, as you cannot get the length of `None` (`TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
)`, and `"Not a list"` will be returned.

```
try:
    t_copy=[]
    n=len(t)
    i=0
    while i<n:
        t_copy.append(t[i])
        i+=1
    return t_copy
except TypeError:
    return "Not a list"
```

Comment: This code may still fail the test when passed a non-list, non-None value.

Comment: Its still failing for None input

Comment: This does NOT fail the None test, although it will fail if passed a dict

Answer (score 0):

Just throw it into a `for` loop, the `if type` should catch anything else.

```
def copy_list(t):
    if type(t) is list:
        t_copy=[]
        for i in t:
            t_copy.append(i)
        return t_copy
    else:
        return "Not a list"
y = None
x = copy_list(y)
print x
y = "abc"
x = copy_list(y)
print x
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
x = copy_list(y)
print x
```

Or more succinctly:

```
def copy_list(t):
    if type(t) is list:
        t_copy = list(t)
        return t_copy
    else:
        return "Not a list"
y = ""
x = copy_list(y)
print x,"\t", type(y)
y = []
x = copy_list(y)
print x,"\t\t", type(y)
y = None
x = copy_list(y)
print x,"   ", type(y)
y = 10
x = copy_list(y)
print x,"   ", type(y)
y = "abc"
x = copy_list(y)
print x,"   ", type(y)
y = [1,2,3,4]
x = copy_list(y)
print x,"   ", type(y)
y = ["a",2,"b"]
x = copy_list(y)
print x,"   ", type(y)
y = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}
x = copy_list(y)
print x,"   ", type(y)
```

**Results in:**

```
Not a list  <type 'str'>
[]      <type 'list'>
Not a list  <type 'NoneType'>
Not a list  <type 'int'>
Not a list  <type 'str'>
[1, 2, 3, 4]    <type 'list'>
['a', 2, 'b']   <type 'list'>
Not a list  <type 'dict'>
```

Comment: Its still failing for None input

Comment: @Varun I strongly dispute that comment. See the printed results.