# How to throw exception when re.search item is not present in list or dict

Tags: python

I'm reading a file and putting contents into dictionary. I'm writing a method where I search for key and return its value. How do I throw exception if my key is not present in dictionary. For example below is the code I'm testing but I get output of re.search as None for non-match items.
Can I use has_key() method?

```
mylist = {'fruit':'apple','vegi':'carrot'}
for key,value in mylist.items():
    found = re.search('vegi',key)
    if found is None:
       print("Not found")
       else:
       print("Found")
```

Found
Not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use 'in'.

```
mylist = {'fruit':'apple','vegi':'carrot'}

test = ['fruit', 'vegi', 'veg']
for value in test:
    if value in mylist:
        print(value + ' is in the dict, its value : ' + mylist[value])
    else:
        raise Exception(value + ' not in dict.')

# Console
# fruit is in the dict, its value: apple
# vegi is in the dict, its value: carrot
# Exception: veg is not in dict
```

Comment: Thanks. I have one doubt for suppose if key is a string like path (example: {'C:/home/user123': 'user', 'D:/mydir/user234':'user1') and if we want to search with partial key like 'user123' does this works?

Answer (score 3):

Python trends towards the "Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission" model versus "Look Before You Leap". So in your code, don't search for the key *before* trying to pull it's value, just pull for it's value and handle the fallout as needed (and where needed).

*Assuming you're asking how to find one key, and return it's value.

EAFP approach:

```
def some_func(key)
    my_dict = {'fruit':'apple', 'vegi':'carrot'}
    return my_dict[key]   # Raises KeyError if key is not in my_dict
```

If a LBYP is what you have to do, try this:

```
def some_func(key):
    my_dict = {'fruit':'apple', 'vegi':'carrot'}
    if not key in my_dict:
        raise SomeException('my useful exceptions message')
    else:
        return my_dict[key]
```

The biggest problem with the LBYP approach is that it introduces a race condition; the 'key' may or may not exist between checking for it, then returning it's value (which is only possible when doing current work).

Answer (score 0):

@JRazor gave you several ways of using list comprehension, lambda and filter for doing what you call a "has_key() method" (I get `SyntaxError`s when I copy/paste them to python 2.7 interpreter though?)

Here's the literal answer to your question: *"How do I throw exception if my key is not present in dictionary?"*

What many languages refer to as `throw` (an exception), python calls `raise` (an exception). 
More info on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957829/how-to-use-raise-keyword-in-python).

In your case, you could add a custom exception like so:

```
mylist = {'fruit':'apple','vegi':'carrot'} # mylist is a dictionary. Just sayin'

if "key" not in mylist:
    raise Exception("Key not found")
else:
    print "Key found"
```