# how to show Filefield validation error django instead of raising exception?

Tags: python, django, filefield

I'm trying to add validation to a filefiled, I used [this snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2206/) and it works, but the problem is that it raises an exception when the file extension does not match, but I just want it to show form validation errors, not raising errors.
How can I do that?

Comment: How can you show the error if you never raise it in the first place?

Comment: yes, I'm asking about how to add the error to the form's errors dict?, how can I access the form?

Comment: You don't need to do that yourself. Any `ValidationError` raised when you call `form.is_valid()` will be caught and added to the error dict. That's how it's supposed to work. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the `raise forms.ValidationError(_('Filetype not supported.'))` in line 38 to the action **you** want to occur when the `Filetype` is not supported.

Python [`raise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13957829/1714410) raises an exception, replacing it with a different command will stop python from "raising" that specific exception.

Comment: yes, I'm asking about how to  add the error to the form's errors dict?, how can I access the form?